# How to set a default field in my class for make a migration to my sqlite db at Django Rest?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have issues when I'm trying to execute the following code at Ubuntu terminal:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
```

I need to add a field called 'album' in my class named music, like that:

`models.py` file

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Music(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'music'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    seconds = models.IntegerField()
    album = models.ForeignKey('Album', related_name='musics')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Album(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'album'

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    band = models.ForeignKey('Band', related_name='albuns')
    date = models.DateField()
```

`serializers.py` file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Music, Band, Album, Member


class MusicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Music
        fields = '__all__'

class BandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Band
        fields = '__all__'
```

My error obtained:

```
(music) leonardo.oliveira@dss-skinner:~/django_music/myapi$ python manage.py makemigrations
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'album' to music without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
Select an option: 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is, It is trying to add an album field in music model. According to defination of this field

```
album = models.ForeignKey('Album', related_name='musics')
```

it is a non-nullable field. instant fix would be

```
album = models.ForeignKey('Album', related_name='musics', null=True)
```

but if you want to add a default album for this field you can add a default by doing something like this.

```
album = models.ForeignKey('Album', related_name='musics', default=Album.objects.first())
```

but for this to work you should have atleast one album present in DB.

After doing these changes you run

```
python manage.py migrate
```